# Can we get a rental car from near Edinburgh's Waverly station?

Tags: car-rentals, train-stations, edinburgh

We are traveling by train from London to Edinburgh's Waverly station. We need to get a rental car once we arrive. Can we arrange for a rental car company to pick us up at the station? Or is there a shuttle or something similar that we can take?

Comment: Oops. We just found the rental car company on the map and it's very close to the station. We can easily walk. Sorry.

Comment: If you've found an answer, post it as an answer below; it may help future travellers with the same question (the more detailed you can make your answer, the better).

Answer (score 1):

The car hire company Enterprize offer a service called "we'll pick you up" - if you call the local office after you book they will pick you up in a car off their and drive you to their office. Other companies may have offices close to the station.

Answer (score 1):

Europcar has an office in the station. I think they use the New Street car park a couple of minute's walk away.